# Using a loop to calculate BIC with high dimensional data in R studio? (my code keeps giving me errors)

Tags: r, loops

I am working with a large high dimensional data set (So P>N). I am attempting to use **BIC** for model selection. Here is what I am doing in R studio:

X is my predictor matrix and Y is my outcome vector.

```
 fit <- glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1) #finding LASSO, find 100 lambda's 

 models <- list() 

 for(i in 1:100) { 

 models[[i]] = fit 

 } 

BIC(models)
```

This results in an error which states `"Error in UseMethod("logLik") : no applicable method for 'loglik' applied to an object of class "list""`

I also attempt to compute BIC while in the loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:100){ 

 BIC(models[i]) 

}
```

Which gives me the same error.

Comment: hey, you need do BIC(models[[i]]) to call out each element. I suggest you do sapply(models,BIC)..

Comment: This , `1:100(models)`, is wrong since `100` is not a function. Just use `for ( i in 1:100)`. Try `BIC(models[[i]])` since "[[" returns a value but "[" always returns a list.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I used sapply(models,BIC), lapply(models,BIC), and mapply(models,BIC). It is coming up with the following error:
"Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('elnet', 'glmnet')"

Comment: Should my code look like this?:  for (i in 1:100) {  \newline BIC(models[[i]]) \newline sapply(models,BIC)

Comment: Hey Mistah, so BIC is defined as BIC = ln(n)*k-2*log(L) where n is the number of datapoints, k is the number of parameters and L is the likelihood. So you need to calculate the number of non-zeros coefficients as k. This is why there is no predefined BIC function ...

Comment: You can see this publication for more infor https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1194461726.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to compute the likelihood now. How does one find the MSE of a glmnet function?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87345/calculating-aic-by-hand-in-r) on how to calculate BIC, so we first create a function that calculates it based on the log likelihood.

```
minustwologLik = function(fit){
n=length(fit$residuals)
deviance = sum(fit$residuals^2)
n*(log(deviance/n) + 1 + log(2*pi))
}

BIC_manual = function(fit,n,k){
log(n)*k + minustwologLik(fit)
}
```

We can test it for normal glms:

```
set.seed(100)
X = matrix(rnorm(5000),ncol=50)
Y = rnorm(100)
lmf = glm(Y~X)
# k is number of predictors + 2 because
# we have an intercept and we estimate the error
BIC_manual(lmf,nrow(X),ncol(X)+2)
[1] 446.8827
BIC(lmf)
[1] 446.8827
```

Now we have a working BIC function. Suppose we want to test 10 values of lambda

```
library(glmnet)
lambda = runif(10,min=0,max=0.1)
models <- list()
for(i in 1:10) {
 fit =  glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1,lambda=lambda[i])
 # we store the residuals
 fit$residuals = predict(fit,X)-Y
 models[[i]] = fit
 }
```

To calculate BIC, we do:

```
results=sapply(1:length(models),function(i){
BIC_manual(models[[i]],nrow(X),models[[i]]$df+4)
})
```

Here I think the k is number of non zero coefficents + 4 , because you have intercept, alpha,beta and error. It does not quite matter if you compare between models, as this will be constant between models. What matters is to get the number of nonzero coefficients.

For MSE, it is the deviance we were calculating. If you have glmnet, you can do for example

```
deviance.glmnet(models[[1]])
```

We collect the MSE in a similar way:

```
MSE=sapply(models,deviance.glmnet)
```

So the results:

```
            lambda      BIC      MSE
1  0.003344587 447.2294 46.75395
2  0.028688622 408.8085 55.32970
3  0.056700061 370.3395 65.44696
4  0.078313596 362.2118 72.54230
5  0.090647978 359.2993 77.25786
6  0.062240390 359.1432 67.18382
7  0.077180937 361.6381 72.12735
8  0.044374976 382.2904 61.34681
9  0.088453015 358.1662 76.38739
10 0.069375991 357.8248 69.42866
```

Comment: thank you so much. this was incredibly helpful. just one more question, how would I get the corresponding beta's to the BIC

Comment: @MistahWhite which beta are you referring to? The coefficients?